# Troubleshooting communication with ESP-12e

Tags: esp8266

I have an ESP-12e and set it up like [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Getting-Started-with-the-ESP8266-ESP-12/) with the exception that I am using FT232RL chip. The problem is I can't receive anything from the module despite the command I send. When I try to connect the `REST` pin to ground for a second I get garbage on putty.

What I tried:

1. Different baud rates.
2. Connecting `REST` pin to ground for a second.
3. Used CR after LF and vice-versa in Putty.
4. Used ESPlorer software.
5. Powering it from a standalone 3.3V line from an ATX power supply instead of using a 3.3 voltage regulator.

If I'm not mistaken I have seen that some are using capacitors with the 3.3V line going to the module (Which I am not using). Anything we can do before concluding the chip is broken? Because I haven't run it in a like a year.

Comment: The default baud rate for esp devices is 74480 if I'm not mistaken .. or 74840 ... it's a very strange baud rate ... are you using it with AT+ commands or are you programming it? I think the AT+ commands source is 115200 baud

Comment: Well I found out I am connecting in firmware mode through GPIO pin to ground. I disconnected it and now I can see it but through termite not putty.

Comment: Try programming it ... download esptool or the espressif flash download tool and program it before declaring it gone  .. also you may have inverted the tx and rx pins (seems to be very simple and sometimes you assume you know the pins and just connect them .. I know I've done that many times)

Comment: Then maybe try clearing CR and LF ... try using putty in the simples way possible, it has to work

Comment: I will look into your suggestions. Thank you very much! :) What do you mean by clearing CR and LF?

Comment: Sorry .. drugs hehehe ... I meant that maybe when you started playing around with putty's configurations you might have missed a config and now it doesn't show anything because the configuration is wrong ... also happened to me a couple of times ... just reset putty to the initial most basic configuration and it should work

Comment: For the moment termite works fine and I think I will keep using it. I really started to hate Putty for its stupid configuration system :\

Comment: I know what you mean .... putty sucks until it doesn't ... in my case, when all others fail putty is always there to save me ... but its anoying, especially when you have to close the terminal and reopen putty because it closed everything